# how to do angularjs dynamic routing based on condtion?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

i have pages like login, userdetails,store,booking .once user logged in select the store and moving to booking page without enter the userdetails.in booking page  onsubmit i want to check whether userdetaills already there r not if its not there i need to redirect to my profile once user submitted details properly again  need to redirect to booking page.if user logged in and submitted userdetails propery and select store that time i dont want page redirection i think here $location.path() will not work

```js
routes
angular
    .module('myaccount')
    .config(['$stateProvider',
        function($stateProvider) 
            $stateProvider
                .state('myaccount', {
     resolve:{
       "check":function($location)
        { 
         
        }
       },
                    url: '/myaccount',
                    templateUrl: 'modules/myaccount/views/myaccount.html',
                    controller: 'MyaccountController'
                });
        }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

*I would love to know how to do this purely in the `.resolve` block*

You could do it with a combination of `resolve` and `controller`.

```
resolve: {
  checkUserDetails: function (user) {
    return user.details.submitted; /** some promise **/
  }
},
controller: function (checkUserDetails, $state) {
  if (!checkUserDetails) {
    $state.go('profile');
  }
}
```

Ensure that you return a promise in the `resolve.checkUserDetails` and inject it into the controller.

---

Unfortunately I don't know / haven't figured out how to do something like this purely in the  `resolve` block (which would be blimping **awesome**!).

So if anyone can come up with how to do that, I'd say that is your best bet.

Until then, this should do *just fine*.